# Actionscript 3 - Path Overlapping

Tags: actionscript-3, vector-graphics

I am somewhat new to Actionscript 3. I am building a svg export / import in flash and need to make the preview behave the same as svg. In flash, if a path overlaps, it is removed. How do I make it fill the entire area?

The paths are created with this:

```
object.graphics.moveTo(xpos[i], ypos[i]);
object.graphics.lineTo(px, py);
```

The result is [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by graphics path winding.

[image: graphics-path-winding]

[Defining winding rules](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1EE3740D-F65C-43bf-9B12-74E34D7D1CBE.html)
[flash.diplay.GraphicsPathWinding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/GraphicsPathWinding.html)

In Flash, the default winding rule is even odd.

For graphics produced using `drawPath`, add `GraphicsPathWinding.NON_ZERO` winding to your drawPath:

```
import flash.display.GraphicsPathWinding;

graphics.drawPath(new <int>[], new <Number>[], GraphicsPathWinding.NON_ZERO);
```

For graphics drawn using convenience methods such as `lineTo()`, `drawCircle()`, or `drawRect()`, you could `beginFill()` and `endFill()` per shape drawn, as in:

[image]

```
var g:Graphics = graphics;

g.beginFill(0x123456)
g.drawRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
g.endFill();

g.beginFill(0x123456)
g.drawRect(125, 125, 50, 50);
g.endFill();
```

Instead of:

[image: even-odd]

```
var g:Graphics = graphics;

g.beginFill(0x123456)
g.drawRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
g.drawRect(125, 125, 50, 50);
g.endFill();
```

Comment: You have the weirdest but most interesting collection of knowledge I know.

Comment: Coming back to this: beginFill, endFill for lineto doesn't work. The overlapping in question is the result of one continuous "lineto". (Reference the picture above.) I am working on converting the lineto to drawPath.